# err: No persister for: web.BackEndModel.TeamDetailsDb

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

I tried to run the Nhibernate in my project but it throughing one error "No persister for: web.BackEndModel.TeamDetailsDb" below is my solution explore.

my project hierarchy

> solution : NhibernateClient
>
> project : web
>
> ```
> folder : BackEndModel
>
>   File : TeamDetailsDb.cs
>
> folder : Controller
>
> folder : model
>
> folder : view
> ```
>
> file : web.hbm.xml

and this is the piece of code i used for saving the data

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
            cfg.SetProperty("dialect", "NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect");
            cfg.SetProperty("connection.driver_class", "NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver");
            cfg.SetProperty("connection.connection_string", "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=OPLsite;Integrated Security=True");
            //cfg.SetProperty("proxyfactory.factory_class", "NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu");
           // cfg.AddAssembly("");
            ISessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
            ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
            ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();



            TeamDetailsDb command = new TeamDetailsDb();
            command.OwnerName = collection["OwnerName"];
            command.TeamName = collection["TeamName"];
            session.Save(command);
            transaction.Commit();
            session.Close();
```

and this is my web.hbm.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   namespace="web.BackEndModel.TeamDetailsDb"
                   assembly="web">

  <class name="TeamDetailsDb" table="TeamDetails">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="int">
      <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="OwnerName"  column="OwnerName" type="String"/>
    <property name="TeamName"   column="TeamName"  type="String"/>
    <mapping resource="web.hbm.xml" assembly="web" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and this is my web config file..

```
     <configSections>
    <section  name="nhibernate" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>

  <nhibernate>
    <add key="hibernate.connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
    <add key="hibernate.dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect" />
    <add key="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver" />
    <add key="hibernate.connection.connection_string" value="Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;" />
  </nhibernate>
```

my teamDetailsDb.cs

i am very new to this, please help me on this, pls becoz i am running out of time....

Answer (score 0):

Yes thank you to all, I found out the reason why it was not working
i changed

```
cfg.SetProperty("dialect", "NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect");
```

to

```
cfg.SetProperty("dialect", "NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect");
```

also i changed the *Web.hbm.xml* to *TeamDetailsDb.hbm.xml*

now my TeamDetailsDb.hbm.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   namespace="web.BackEndModel"
                   assembly="web">

  <class name="TeamDetailsDb" table="TeamDetails">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="int">
      <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="OwnerName"  column="OwnerName" type="String"/>
    <property name="TeamName"   column="TeamName"  type="String"/>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```